# Transfer a cocktail ownership of data from outside G suite domain to a user inside the org

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

I started out as a freelancer and had Google Drive installed on my machine with a Gmail (personal) account. Soon, I got my own domain and setup G suite with it.

What I did next was to create a folder from my personal account (unknowingly because I created it from the G suite's app on my personal PC) which now has a cocktail of users owning and sharing stuff inside my folder. More people came to the organization and the condition kept getting worse.

Now, my drive is almost full and the one way I know is to fully download every doc and upload it again. Can anyone suggest any other way to change the ownership of the data from my personal account to the G suite's account?